# what does this ... (three dots) means in c++

Tags: c++

It may seems a silly question, but when I try to look at this answer in SOF,

[Compile time generated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334752/compile-time-generated-tables)

I noted statements such as this:

```
template<
    typename IntType, std::size_t Cols, 
    IntType(*Step)(IntType),IntType Start, std::size_t ...Rs
> 
constexpr auto make_integer_matrix(std::index_sequence<Rs...>)
{
    return std::array<std::array<IntType,Cols>,sizeof...(Rs)> 
        {{make_integer_array<IntType,Step,Start + (Rs * Cols),Cols>()...}};
}
```

more specifically :

```
std::size_t ...Rs
```

or

```
std::index_sequence<Rs...>
```

what does ... means here?

## Edit 1

The question that reported as the original question related to this question is not correct:

That question can not answer these two cases (as they are not functions with variable number of arguments)

```
std::size_t ...Rs
std::index_sequence<Rs...>
```

But this is a good explanation:

https://xenakios.wordpress.com/2014/01/16/c11-the-three-dots-that-is-variadic-templates-part/

Comment: https://xenakios.wordpress.com/2014/01/16/c11-the-three-dots-that-is-variadic-templates-part/

Comment: They specify [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments), see the duplicate link for how they are used.

Comment: @CoryKramer :Thanks, but they don't, as for example std::size_t ...Rs is not a function with variable number of arguments, it is a template with variable number of argument as explained in the blog.

Comment: @CoryKramer Your "duplicate question" is not a complete duplicate of this, as this contains a question about variadic templates in addition to variadic arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-type variadic function templates in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877293/non-type-variadic-function-templates-in-c11)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Its called a parameter pack and refers to zero or more template parameters:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

```
std::size_t ...Rs
```

is the parameter pack of type `std::size_t`. 
A variable of that type (e.g. `Rs... my_var`) can be unpacked with:

```
my_var...
```

This pattern is heavily used in forwarding an (unknown) amount of arguments:

```
template < typename... T >
Derived( T&&... args ) : Base( std::forward< T >( args )... )
{
}
```

Comment: But why do we need to "forwarding an (unknown) amount of arguments" ?

Comment: @Henry For example, to get command line parameters. Also, printf uses that.