# What does ... means in c code

Tags: c, wiredtiger

I'm reading the code of [wiredtiger](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.9.2/struct_w_t___c_u_r_s_o_r.html#ad1088d719df40babc1f57d086691ebdc).  I see a function definition as

`WT_CURSOR::set_key(WT_CURSOR *  cursor, ...)`

what does the '...' means here?   how can the compiler compile such code?

Thanks

Comment: It means a variable number of parameters can follow.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792417/what-does-this-three-dots-means-in-c

Comment: @zvi That question is about template parameter packs, not about variable number of arguments.

Comment: As in library function prototypes such as `int printf(const char *format [, argument] ... );`

Comment: Observation: the `::` means that the code is C++ and not C.

Comment: Like others have said it means the function takes a variable number of arguments. That's said, this particular call, has its argument length capped by the number of fields declared in the wiredtiger table with ``create_table``. Which means that you must match the number of key columns in your table.

Comment: I mean to say `session->create` instead of `create_table`.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the function accepts a variable number of arguments after the named arguments (possibly zero).  The function would use a `va_list` and the associated functions (`va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end`) to process the arguments.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// n: number of doubles
// ... list of doubles
double average(int n, ...)
{
    double accum = 0.0;
    int i;
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        accum += va_arg(vl, double);
    }
    va_end(vl);
    return accum/(double)n;
}

int main()
{
    double avg = average(5, 1.0, 1.0, 6.5, 3.3, -5.8);
    printf("%f\n", avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `1.200000`

Comment: Thanks,   I just read this [artical](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/c-variable-argument-list-access/),  I am still confused with the first parameter.    in the wiredtiger case,     ``` WT_CURSOR *cursor;  session->create(session, "table:kvtab", "key_format=S,value_format=S"); session->open_cursor(session, "table:kvtab", NULL, NULL, &cursor); cursor->set_key(cursor, "key1");```  what does the first parameter means here?

Comment: @zhihuifan which one is the first parameters? Like I said above, the number of arguments depends on the number of columns in the key part of the table (and similarly with set_value in value part of the table). So it depends on this call `session->create(session, "table:kvtab", "key_format=S,value_format=S")`

Comment: If you don't understand the API of wiredtiger, I recommend you have a look at how sophia database system does handle the same semantic.